# cx_Freeze - Building exe - Windows 64bit - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Trying to build a exe file but am having an error I don't understand. I followed a tutorial so unless it had bad instructions I don't see what is wrong.  [cmd print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjGai.png)

-Code-

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('Wedgie la Apple.py')]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name='Wedgie la Apple'
    options={'build_exe':{'packages':['pygame'],'incude_files':['apple.png','appleIcon.png','grass.png','intro.png','rock.png','snakeBody.png','snakeHead.png','intro.wav','select.wav','music1.wav','music2.wav','music3.wav','music4.wav','nom_nom_nom1.wav','nom_nom_nom2.wav','nom_nom_nom3.wav','death_3.wav','death_4.wav','death_6.wav']}},

    description = 'Wedgie la Apple - Snake Game'
    executables = executables


    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `,`between keywords - like `name='Wedgie la Apple',`

Example function:

```
>>> def a(a="abc", b="cef"):
...     print(a, b)
```

Wrong:

```
>>> a(a="abcdef" b="feggsef")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a(a="abcdef" b="feggsef")
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Working:

```
>>> a(a="abcdef", b="feggsef")
abcdef feggsef
```

Comment: Accept the answer then please :)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow. I accepted your answer. Cheers!